# circular reference class loading in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, reference, cyclic-reference

In CodeIgniter I have a model named `User_Model` and another one named `Product_Model`

Now in the `User_Model` constructor I am loading couple of models that I use in the class.

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::construct();
    $this->load-model("Product_Model");
    //load some more models I need...
  } 
}
```

While working on products, I need sometimes to be using the user model, so I do:

```
class Product_Model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::construct();
    $this->load-model("User_Model");
    //load some more models I need...
  } 
}
```

The problem is that since these are in circular reference, I am getting `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached`. I am using `xdebug` and I know that it has settings to remove this. My question is  - what is the correct way to handle this without increasing setting limitations. How should I restructure the architecture?

I know that if I am using `PHP` without `codeigniter`, and create circular references (class A loads class B, class B loads class A), PHP will load it for N times (I think it is three) and then mark it as `*recursive*.`

But we are faced with such a situation, what is the best way to refactor?

Comment: Why not just autoload both models, You seem to need them?

Comment: Does either model actually require an instance of the other, or does it just need some values from that class - in which case pass the values into the constructor or method

Comment: @jtheman - the problem with autoloading is that they are being used all over the place with aliases, and CI autoloading does not seem to allow loading a model with an alias name :-(

Comment: @UndefinedVariable what version of CI you have ? is it `2.2.0` or `3.0 dev`

Comment: @user574632 - both models use the methods of the other model. For each in User class I do `$this->product->getProductList();` -- this will get the product list for that user. I can technically pass the user to get the product list I guess...but there are other examples which are bit more complex

Comment: @karanthakkar - its not the dev branch. the latest stable branch whichever it is. should be 2.2.0

Comment: Now I'm lost, why would you want to alias a model?

Comment: if `2.2.0` yes you are correct `CCI does not allow autoload model with alias` but in `3.0-dev` it does allow `autoload with alias` but you can auto load. `it wont effect the alias given in other controllers` they will use by alias.

Comment: Thats good to know, sadly I cannot upgrade at the moment..

Comment: in that case i would recommend a refactor to except a user id or similar in the method or constructor. It may be complicated but what you have is not a good design.

Comment: @jtheman, most of the models were already aliased by the time I took over. Some models have ridiculously long names and some are aliased just to remove the _model from them...

Comment: @user574632 - what you said is true. However even if I need to pass the user id to a method in product class while I am in user_model, I still need to load the product class...

Comment: Yes, and that will be fine, its the 2 way dependency that is causing your issue. Probably you actually need one higher level class that has both a user and product model as properties, then passes relevent data between them, eg `$usersProducts = $this->productModel->getProductsByUser($this->userModel->getID);`

Comment: @UndefinedVariable you can copy `5-6` lines form CI `3.0-dev` core into your `2.2.0` and can achieve the task but if you want. i myself strictly avoid editing core files.

Comment: @karanthakkar - do you know what those `5-6` lines are?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable there is minor changes in autoloading model in both CI.
you can get `3.0-dev` from here https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter open `system/core/loader.php` of both find `public function model` in both and replace your `2.2.0`. now you can load like `$autoload['model'] = array('first_model' => 'first');`.its hardly `5-6` line changes.you can copy whole function no worries. cant write steps in comment.

Comment: @karanthakkar - thank you, you should add your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @UndefinedVariable glad to help. posted it as answer. cheers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI `2.2.0` does not allow autoloading model with alias but `3.0-dev` does support it.
since you have CI `2.2.0` you need to copy a function from `3.0-dev` core to your `2.2.0` core.

**Seps** :

1. Get CI `3.0-dev` from [Github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter)
2. Open `system/core/loader.php` of CI `3.0-dev`.
3. Find `public function model` function.
4. Replace it in your `system/core/loader.php` of CI `2.2.0`.
5. Now you can autoload like `$autoload['model'] = array('first_model' => 'first');`

**Note** : This is solution for those who want autoloading model with alias but having CI `2.2.0`